# Saving a HTTP get response to a file

Tags: c#, http

I cannot get the HTTP response to be saved to a text file. I can make a get request and I can see that it goes through and I get the response I want but it doesn't save to a file. My code is below, I have commented out the other solution I have tried.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = TextBox1.Text;
    string sURL;
    sURL = "http://api.urlvoid.com/api1000/key/host/" + input + "/";
    HttpWebRequest wrGETURL = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    HttpWebResponse wrResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrGETURL.GetResponse();
    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\API_Call_Test.txt");
    Stream DataStream = wrResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(DataStream);
    string AllResponse = SR.ReadToEnd();
    //var file = File.Open(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\API_Call_Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
    SW.Write(DataStream);
    //DataStream.CopyTo(file);
    wrResponse.Close();
                
}
```

The Wireshark analysis of the TCP stream:

```
GET /api1000/key/host/mo.gov/                                HTTP/1.1
Host: api.urlvoid.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 16:31:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 909
Age: 0


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<details>
 <host>host</host>
 <updated>1463838832</updated>
 <http_response_code>200</http_response_code>
 <domain_age>0</domain_age>
 <google_page_rank>0</google_page_rank>
 <alexa_rank>0</alexa_rank>
 <connect_time>0.005995</connect_time>
 <header_size>959</header_size>
 <download_size>54726</download_size>
 <speed_download>67090</speed_download>
 <external_url_redirect></external_url_redirect>
 <ip>
<addr>104.16.20.39</addr>
<hostname></hostname>
<asn>13335</asn>
<asname>CloudFlare, Inc.</asname>
<country_code>US</country_code>
<country_name>United States</country_name>
<region_name>California</region_name>
<city_name>San Francisco</city_name>
<continent_code>NA</continent_code>
<continent_name>North America</continent_name>
<latitude>37.7697</latitude>
<longitude>-122.393</longitude>
 </ip>
</details>
<page_load>0.00</page_load>
</response>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that would be something like below. I think you can adapt it just fine.

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
string file = "response.txt";
string content = string.Empty;

// set up request/response
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

// read response content
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream ?? new MemoryStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();

// write to file on desktop
File.WriteAllText(
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), file), 
    content, 
    Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not writing the request data and you need a stream reader to read data:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = TextBox1.Text;
    string sURL;
    sURL = "http://api.urlvoid.com/api1000/key/host/" + input + "/";
    HttpWebRequest wrGETURL = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    using (Stream stm = wrGETURL.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(input);
        }
    }
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string resultString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\API_Call_Test.txt"))
            File.Delete(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\API_Call_Test.txt");
        File.Create(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\API_Call_Test.txt").Close();
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\API_Call_Test.txt", resultString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var resul = response.GetResponseStream())
using(var file = File.Create(your_path_file))

resul.CopyTo(file);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.